# shell command to find a process id and attach to it?

Tags: bash, domain-driven-design, grep

I want to attach to a running process using 'ddd', what I manually do is:

```
# ps -ax | grep PROCESS_NAME
```

Then I get a list and the pid, then I type:

```
# ddd PROCESS_NAME THE_PID
```

Is there is a way to type just one command directly?

Remark: When I type `ps -ax | grep PROCESS_NAME`, grep will match both the process and `grep` command line itself.

Comment: You can eliminate `grep -v grep` by using `grep [P]ROCESS_NAME` - putting square brackets around the first character of the process name makes the shell interpret that as one of a list of one character ("P" in this case) but `grep` sees the literal bracket-P-bracket in the output of `ps` so it doesn't match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an easy way to get rid of the grep process:

```
ps -ax | grep PROCESS_NAME | grep -v ' grep '
```

(as long as the process you're trying to find doesn't include the string `" grep "`).

So something like this should work in a script (again, assuming there's only one copy running):

```
pid=$(ps -ax | grep $1 | grep -v ' grep ' | awk '{print $1}')
ddd $1 ${pid}
```

If you call your script `dddproc`, you can call it with:

```
dddproc myprogramname
```

Although I'd add some sanity checks such as detecting if there's zero or more than one process returned from `ps` and ensuring the user supplies an argument.

Comment: Your answer is half the solution. I was expecting some grep command that would yield only the PID, so then I can do something like:

ddd PROCESS_NAME $(THE_MAGIC_GREP_COMMAND)

Comment: @lallous, the `grep | grep -v | awk` will give you the PID of the processs. `grep -v grep` strips out the (grep process) line you're complaining about and `awk '{print $1}' gives you just the PID.

Answer (score 1):

As separate commands:

```
% PID=`ps -ax | grep ${PROCESS_NAME} | grep -v grep | cut -d ' ' -f 1-2`
% ddd ${PROCESS_NAME} ${PID}
```

In one line:

```
% PID=`ps -ax | grep ${PROCESS_NAME} | grep -v grep | cut -d ' ' -f 1-2` && ddd ${PROCESS_NAME} ${PID}
```

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 10's bash, and this worked:

$ ddd ${PROCESS_NAME} $(ps -ax | grep ${PROCESS_NAME} | grep -v grep | cut -d ' ' -f 1)

Thanks!

Comment: @lallous: yes, that looks to be equivalent - TMTOWTDI, as they say... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Do this way -

```
ddd PROCESS_NAME \`ps -ax | grep PROCESS_NAME | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}'\`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ddd <process_name> `pgrep <process_name>`
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use pggrep to find the process

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk to both filter and get the column you want. The "exit" limits the ps results to the first hit.

```
function ddd_grep() {
  ddd $(ps -ax | awk -v p="$1" '$4 == p { print $1; exit 0; }');
}

ddd_grep PROCESS_NAME
```

You may have to adjust the columns for your ps output. Also you can change the `==` to `~` for regex matching.