# How to open process again in linux terminal?

Tags: python, linux, ssh, terminal

From my home pc using putty, I ssh'ed into a remote server, and I ran a python program that takes hours to complete, and as it runs it prints stuff. Now after a while, my internet disconnected, and I had to close and re-open putty and ssh back in. If I type 'top' I can see the python program running in the background with its PID number. Is there a command I can use to basically re-open that process and see it printing its stuff again?

Thanks

Comment: You [screen](http://www.rackaid.com/blog/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/) or [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) on your server to have processes running when you disconnect.

Comment: I think you should use screen in the first place.

Comment: Look here, it shows you how to use screen for your problem:
http://linuxcommando.blogspot.com/2013/10/how-to-use-screen-command-to-run.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted, best practice is to use screen or tmux (before starting the program, so you do not need to ask this question).

But you can also attach to a running process with a debugger such as gdb (alluded to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833355/shell-command-to-find-a-process-id-and-attach-to-it) as `ddd`, a wrapper for gdb), as well as with strace (see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58550/how-to-view-the-output-of-a-running-process-in-another-bash-session)).  That's better than nothing - but gdb and strace would not give you the program's command-line again (though [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31824/how-to-attach-terminal-to-detached-process) suggests a way).  At least strace could give you some clues of what the program was attempting to print.

Answer (score 0):

Things to try:

`nohup`, or

`screen`