# Reading the console output of a process through SSH, linux

Tags: linux, ssh, console, slackware

I have a process running on Slackware 13.37 that outputs data to its terminal window. Is it possible to read/redirect this output to ssh window/PuTTY without terminating/restarting the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can capture the output using shell redirection or via a program such as [`script`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html) -- provided that your program was started "in the usual way". (It is possible to write via special devices to other terminals, given appropriate permissions).

One assumes that you already know about redirecting output, e.g.,

```
foo >bar
```

but have some case, e.g., a GUI program which continues to write to the terminal.

Without worrying about interfering with a program by redirecting its output, I would run `script` and start the program within the shell that `script` starts.  Then anything written from that shell would go to the `typescript` file (by default).

On the other hand, GUI programs which *start* a terminal window may/may not be configurable to allow customizing them with a startup script that can capture output.

As noted in [How to open process again in linux terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28891305/how-to-open-process-again-in-linux-terminal/28891516#28891516), it is possible to attach to a running process with [strace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace), given its process-ID. Using the `-e` option as described in [7 Strace Examples to Debug the Execution of a Program in Linux](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/11/strace-examples/), you could just extract `write` calls.

Keep in mind with `strace` that nonprinting characters from the writes are converted to printable text, and that `strace` displays function arguments up to a fixed limit (which you can adjust using the `-s` option).  The output of `strace` can be redirected (and it need not be run on the same terminal as the original process).

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to mention that I cannot terminate/restart the process as this would disrupt a lot of running services.

Comment: I was more thinking of filtering the strace log for write syscalls.